# how do I reference a variable in fish shell with a default fallback

Tags: shell, fish

What is the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) equivalent to the following bash:

```
echo ${TEST:-1}
```

In bash this would print the value of TEST if there was one, or 1 if there was not.

Comment: See also https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3926#issuecomment-290442534 for explanation of some maintainers.

Answer (score 15):

I believe you need temponary variable (or a function). If `$TEST` doesn't exist, it's expanded to nothing, and `$test_or` only contains `1`. It would be nice to have real way of doing that, but currently the syntax is issue, and it doesn't appear it's really needed for most purposes.

```
set test_or $TEST 1
echo $test_or[1]
```

Also, if all you want is to modify `$TEST` if it doesn't exist already, you can use `set -q`.

```
set -q TEST; or set TEST 1
echo $TEST
```

Answer (score 8):

To reference a variable and provide a default value in-line you can use command substitution containing a conditional which does `echo` on both branches.

```
> echo (if set -q someVar; echo $someVar; else; echo 'a default value'; end)
a default value
> set someVar 42
> echo (if set -q someVar; echo $someVar; else; echo 'a default value'; end)
42
```

Since this is kind of verbose, you could initialize the variable on a different line when it is unset.

```
> echo $otherVar

> set -q otherVar; or set otherVar 'a default value'
> echo $otherVar
a default value
```

If you really want the ability to substitute a default in-line, you can do it in a function using indirection, and then call that function.

```
> function orDefault
      set -q $argv[1]; and echo $$argv[1]; or echo $argv[2]
  end
>
> echo $moreVar

> echo (orDefault moreVar 'a default value')
a default value
> set moreVar 42
> echo (orDefault moreVar 'a default value')
42
```